# Django ManyToManyField how to add created_at and updated_at

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How can I add created_at and updated_at fields to my ManyToManyField?

```
class Profile (models.Model):  
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Group(models.Model):
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='groups')
```

Comment: By defining a "through" model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `ManyToManyField` with an argument named `though`.
More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

```
class Group(models.Model):
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='groups',
                    through='GroupProfileRelationship')

class Profile (models.Model):  
    # fields
```

Now here's the through model

```
class GroupProfileRelationship(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> Note that some options will no longer available. such as `add()` `remove()`
>
> Really important to take a look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Comment: should there be no class on GroupProfileRelationShip? lowercase S ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake I updated. Depending on the name of your through models, this `through='GroupProfileRelationShip'` should be the same name as the class

Comment: looks like you need `through_fields=('group', 'profile'),` as well

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work with "GroupProfileRelationship" but it does work with "Membership" go figure =) thanks for the help!